# Meteor - automatically updating canvas with subscribed data?

Tags: meteor

I might be missing something, but it seems that Meteor's "magic" revolves around binding data to DOM elements, and updating text and HTML fragments via handlebars:  http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity

This is great, *however*, when trying to write a meteor app that displays live data in a <canvas> element, I cannot figure out the "meteor way" to update my canvas when the live data changes, since the canvas is populated via JS code like:

```
var g = canvas.getContext('2d')
g.fillRect(x, y, w, h)
```

and not data-backed text in the HTML template.

I am trying to draw on the canvas using data from a Meteor.Collection.

My only thought was to embed canvas-drawing JS code in the HTML template in a script tag populated by handlebar vars, but this seems wrong since meteor's events and data-binding code is already client-side JS.

Is there some way listen for live data changes, which triggers drawing on the canvas via JS instead of HTML elements/text?

Please let me know if I can clarify the question in some way

**Update:**
Tom's answer below made me notice Meteor.deps, which look to allow executing arbitrary code in a reactive context: 
http://docs.meteor.com/#on_invalidate

I will try this out and update here if it works.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant by "embedded ... in a script tag".
currently I'm doing something like putting {{drawCanvas}} in the template containing my canvas, and do all the drawing inside the funcion that's part of Template.canvas.helper named "drawCanvas", this function returns nothing, so nothing gets rendered, but it is executed so it will update the canvas. Is that what you already attempted? The Template.name.helper is automatically reactive so as long as it depends on a ReactiveDict or some model it will update accordingly as it's changed

Comment: What I meant by that comment was to dynamically generate JS code as a string in the template (which is obviously weird).  My answer below seemed to be the "correct" way with Meteor

Comment: that is indeed absurd! But does my method look alright? The idea is just using an invisible {{drawCanvas}} that does nothing, which gets re-run whenever some reactive data changes (thereby re-drawing the canvas)

Comment: It's sounds like a clever solution!   Might want to compare performance between approaches and report back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
var Shapes = new Meteor.Collection('shapes')

if (Meteor.is_client) {
  // Function that redraws the entire canvas from shapes in Meteor.Collection
  function drawShapes() {
    var shapes = Shapes.find({})
    shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
      // draw each on canvas
    })
  }

  var startUpdateListener = function() {
    // Function called each time 'Shapes' is updated.
    var redrawCanvas = function() {
      var context = new Meteor.deps.Context()
      context.on_invalidate(redrawCanvas) // Ensures this is recalled for each update
      context.run(function() {
        drawShapes()
      })
    }
    redrawCanvas()
  }

  Meteor.startup(function() {
    startUpdateListener()
  })
}
```

Comment: This does work - thanks!  Though what I'm personally looking for is to do the full redraw only on startup - and then only do incremental redraws on update/added/deleted.  Do you the right way to do this sort of thing only on startup/render and not after every update?  If you put queries inside of template.rendered it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The reason I did full redraw is that a Canvas doesn't support removing/updating the individual shapes.  AFAIK, you have to redraw the entire canvas if shapes overlap, etc.

Comment: @semateos You can achieve that behavior by using a library like Pixi.js, which mimics the Flash Display List.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the answer to your question is to use `Collection.observe` (http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) and trigger the relevant redrawing code in the various callbacks.

For instance, something like:

```
Rectangles.observe({
  added: function(rect) {
    var g = canvas.getContext('2d');
    g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
  },
  // etc
})
```

Comment: Thanks mate, didn't see that.  One problem in my particular case is that I need to redraw the entire canvas (e.g. removing a rectangle requires redrawing rectangles under/over it), which implies I need the entire query results, not just added/removed/changed.

Comment: Sure. I guess what you have is the right way to do it then. I wish Meteor had a simpler way to set up a context + deal with invalidation by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble with updating the canvas so I created this simple game demo:
https://github.com/randompast/Meteor-SimpleGame