# With Meteor, why calling MyCollection.findOne affects other template functions?

Tags: meteor

I am using findOne just to fetch one certain element for my collection.

However, when I do that, all my template functions containing those collections are re-run and the content refreshed. The content is similar, the problem is I am applying styles to some of those elements, and these updates just reset everything as well. More importantly: those refreshes are completely useless.

For example, I have this template:

```
Template.content.cars = function () {
    alert("I AM RERUN!");
    return Cars.find();
};
```

And in another function, I am doing this:

```
Cars.findOne({ _id: Session.get('current_car') }, {});
```

Why would be the first template re-run? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your first template would be re-run: are you sure something else isn't going on?

But as a general non-answer to your question: you should expect that a template which depends on the entirety of a collection will be re-run many times (for instance as the data loads incrementally when the page first renders). With meteor you need to write your HTML/CSS in such a way that this re-rendering won't cause problems.

Without knowing more about your problem I can't really say more than that.

Comment: There is probably something else going on with my project, this methods is being run way too many times when I load the page: it's really suspicious.

The real goal is that I will use a Google Maps (or another mapping library) and I will insert pinpoints depending on a collection. But I'm not sure how to "listen" to the changes is that collection, and I can recreate them everything few seconds because something changed... I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Jordy - take a look at these two questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794409/meteor-automatically-updating-canvas-with-subscribed-data/10794614#10794614 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260439/meteor-deps-running-a-client-side-func/11271112#11271112 perhaps the answer is in there somehow?

Comment: Thanks Tom, yes, that is actually what I discovered yesterday late in the night :) I will mark your mark as the accepted answer as that's what I was actually looking for. I still don't know why that template get rerun so many times but there is no flickering or anything so I guess there aren't any re-rendering. Plus using observe on that same collection, I get the recall exactly as expected. I'll stick to that for now :)